# How to close the fancy box after a button is clicked in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using Fancy box to load some content and when a button is clicked the fancy box should close.

Here is my code:

```
function confirmation(){
        var htmlStr = '<div class="form"><form:form id="confirmBox" method="POST" action="tagging">'
        + '<label>Do you want to Map Or Tag? </label>'
        + '<br>'
        + '<br>'
        + '<br>'
        + '<input type="button" name="confMapBtn" id="confMapBtn" value="MAP" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">'

        + '<input type="button" name="confTagBtn" id="confTagBtn" value="TAG" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">'
        + '</form:form></div>';
    $.fancybox.open(htmlStr, {

    'width' : 950,
    'height' : 1100,
    'autoScale' : false,
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'hideOnContentClick' : false,
    'afterLoad': function(){

        $("#confMapBtn").click(function(){
            if($(this).data('clicked', true)){
                mapping();
            }
        });

        $("#confTagBtn").click(function(){
            if($(this).data('clicked', true)){
                tagging();
            }
        });
    }
    });
    }
```

**NOTE:**  Whenever a button is clicked it goes to some function but before that Fancy box should be closed.

**UPDATE:** When a button is clicked from above fancy box another fancy box opens but never mind it, The current fancy box should be closed before showing the fancy box which appears after button click.

Help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: $.fancybox.close(); ?

Comment: Where to use it ?

Comment: On button click, on document, on page load... where ever you want...

Comment: I have updated the question please check

Comment: [Please check here](http://fancybox.net/api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: Use `$.fancybox.close();`  or there will be a class called

`fancybox-close` when fancybox is opened , simply trigger a click on it.

```
$("#confMapBtn").click(function(){
     if($(this).data('clicked', true)){
            mapping();
            $(".fancybox-close").trigger("click");
        }


}
```

**OR**

```
$("#confMapBtn").click(function(){
   if($(this).data('clicked', true)){
            mapping();
           $.fancybox.close();
   }

}
```

Comment: put a alert in click and see if its coming

Comment: `$("#confMapBtn").click(function(){   
            $(".fancybox-close").trigger("click");   
}`    can you simply try this.. without checking the click

Comment: Yeah alert is coming when button is clicked. NOTE: I have put alert before calling function.

Comment: Yeah tried as you said, Fancy box still remains same and its not closing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151040/discussion-between-ethan-hunt-and-bilaljohn).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$.fancybox.close();`, which is [documented in the plugin's readme](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs). You can either call it in the click events themselves, or in the `mapping()` or `tagging()` functions.

For example, you can do this:

```
$("#confMapBtn").click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('clicked', true)) {
    mapping();
    $.fancybox.close();
  }
});

$("#confTagBtn").click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('clicked', true)) {
    tagging();
    $.fancybox.close();
  }
});
```

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  // Dummy functions to check that button click is triggered
  function mapping() {
    console.log('Mapping');
  };
  function tagging() {
    console.log('Tagging');
  };
  
  // Original confirmation function
  function confirmation() {
    var htmlStr = '<div class="form"><form:form id="confirmBox" method="POST" action="tagging">' +
      '<label>Do you want to Map Or Tag? </label>' +
      '<br>' +
      '<br>' +
      '<br>' +
      '<input type="button" name="confMapBtn" id="confMapBtn" value="MAP" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">'

      +
      '<input type="button" name="confTagBtn" id="confTagBtn" value="TAG" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">' +
      '</form:form></div>';
 
    $.fancybox.open(htmlStr, {

      'width': 950,
      'height': 1100,
      'autoScale': false,
      'transitionIn': 'none',
      'transitionOut': 'none',
      'hideOnContentClick': false,
      'afterLoad': function() {

        $("#confMapBtn").click(function() {
          if ($(this).data('clicked', true)) {
            mapping();
            $.fancybox.close();
          }
        });

        $("#confTagBtn").click(function() {
          if ($(this).data('clicked', true)) {
            tagging();
            $.fancybox.close();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
  confirmation();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @eThan_hunT If it does not work, did you check your browser console? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
parent.$.fancybox.close();

See [Fancybox API documentation](http://fancybox.net/api).